# Search inside objects javascript

Tags: javascript, object, firebase

I'm experimenting on login with firebase. I can make an account, and it'll store additional information too. The problem is retrieving this information.

I can get it using:

```
usersRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val())
}, function (errorObject) {...});
```

When I do this I get two things (because I have two accounts):

`-JrrzEOqZQU0HVeYVXCm: Object`, has `uid: "simplelogin:21"` inside of it
`-JrrzgOgQY2z6tNYN0BY: Object`, has `uid: "simplelogin:22"` inside of it

Inside of the second object is the info that I need:

I received `simplelogin:22` from the login.

Is there a way I can search inside of the objects to their uid, and get the rest of the information stored inside of that object?
Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9g0qkqvs/1/)

Comment: Not sure if I understand, but if you're just trying to see what is in `snapshot.val()` you can `console.log(JSON.stringify(snapshot.val()));`

Comment: Yeah but it's not JSON, for some reason
And I can already see what's inside snapshot.val(), namely two other objects. I need to see whats inside those

Comment: I just updated your fiddle and here is what is logs: `usersRef: {"-JrsFcPSlT-rGvBI2swG":{"faveShow1":"utd","faveShow2":"oitnb","faveShow3":"sherlock","uid":"simplelogin:27"},"-JrsGW7F783iVrZOe9QJ":{"faveShow1":"utd","faveShow2":"oitnb","faveShow3":"sherlock","uid":"simplelogin:28"},"-JrsIADDo5pUZkXKrset":{"faveShow1":"oitnb","faveShow2":"utd","uid":"simplelogin:29"},"first":"Wilma","last":"Flintstone"}` See the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/frankvanpuffelen/9g0qkqvs/3/

Comment: Yes Ik now how to log that. I just needed to search for in which -Jrs... thing the quid : simplelogin:X was. But user Robin van der Noord has found the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var thisAuthData = authData.uid;
    //console.log(authData)
    var usersRef = new Firebase("https://fiery-heat-xxx.firebaseio.com/users");
usersRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {
    for(var amount in snapshot.val()){
console.log(snapshot.val()[amount].uid);
//here some if statement thingy's to check with your authData but you can do that yourself I guess ;)
    }
```